# "It's a great thing" in a formal letter?

Tags: formality, business-language

Is it ok to say "it's a great thing that your company does this and that because..." in a business letter or is there another way to say it ?

Comment: Hasn't the great divide between informal speech and business-speak been bridged by prominent figures nowadays?

Comment: A matter of opinion. Hence off topic here. But in my opinion “great” grates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's a great thing that..." should be fine, but something along the lines of "I appreciate that..." or "It is great that..." would be more formal.